# Shibboleth custom redirect after success login

Tags: shibboleth

I need to perform actions after Shibbolethlogin and before redirect to SP url.
For me, the best solution would be "Shib page login" -> login ok -> redirect to my custom page -> redircet to sp url.

How can i do that if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, you need to create a custom HTTP filter as a extension of Shibboleth, make it available on the classpath of Shibboleth IDP application and register it in the descriptor of shibbboleth IPD web application (web.xml).

There's Shibboleth extension that uses this principle to prompt the user to confirm releasing of the attributes from IDP to the SP. The application is uApprove, developed by SWITCH.
You can read more about the application at [uApprove](http://www.switch.ch/aai/support/tools/uApprove.html) and get ideas how to implement your own at [uApprove manual](http://www.switch.ch/aai/downloads/uApprove-manual/)