# Force Shibboleth to redirect to a specific URL after authentication

Tags: shibboleth

I'm trying to fulfill a requirement to always have a user be redirected to the same URL after being authenticated through Shibboleth.

At the moment, it will redirect to the referrer (which can change) which we want to ignore and replace it with our own (that never changes).

**Update #1**

Unsure if I need to do this at the SP or IDP level.

Comment: Is it that you have a service provider (SP) that you want to configure to redirect its clients after receiving the response from the identity provider (IdP)?

Comment: You can use a custom HTTP filter as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629541/shibboleth-custom-redirect-after-success-login

Comment: @rlandster I was thinking/hoping I could set something up in my shibboleth2.xml for my SP.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus were you able to figure out a solution for the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't and simply moved on. Sorry.

Comment: Same here, would love to see if someone has more feedback about this. There is nothing that can be send in the SAML2/POST to indicate what is the redirect URL after successful login ?

Answer (score 0):

I think we have a similar question, I was searching for an answer to my question when I came across yours. To make sure I have you right, and make this question bump up in the search rankings, you're (likely) wanting to have your SP redirect you to a specific URL after login. What is your Stack setup? Apache?

If you look at the Shibboleth documents - specifically:

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPSessionInitiator
and
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPContentSettings
and
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPSessionCreationParameters

you will find that there is a "Location" attribute and a "target" attribute which may meet your needs.

Location (relative path)
The location of the SessionInitiator (when combined with the base handlerURL). This is the location to redirect to when manually initiating a session using the query string protocol.

target (URL) (Version 2.4 and Above)
Allows the resources to return to after SSO to be "locked" to a specific value, even when running as a result of active protection of other resources. In other words, this value overrides the actual resource location when SSO redirection is automatic, including initial access and after a timeout.

In theory you should be able to add these to your configuration. For me I need to figure out how to do this dynamically so if a file is clicked on, after logged in you're re-directed back to it.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same requirement. follow below steps:

You need to make change in your shibboleth idp.  you can create one relying party and specify location of it's metadata file. In this service provider's metadata file, there is one attribute named saml consumer. set this value to where you want to point the user after successful authentication.

In our case, we had only one service provider so we created only one entry in relying party and disabled other/default replying parties. after this we added static SP metadata file which contained url of the consumer.